# LLVM Clang address sanitizer on Linux with Matlab

Tags: linux, matlab, llvm, centos7, address-sanitizer

I tried to use address sanitizer for debug Matlab Mex code. I need invoke Matlab and then run matlab scripts to call Mex function. I did below configuration.

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/llvm_lib_path/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so
export ASAN_OPTIONS=alloc_dealloc_mismatch=0:halt_on_error=false:verbosity=1
```

But when I invoke Matlab, it hang up soon and can not launch the GUI.

I did the similar thing in MacOs and work as expected.

With verbosity=1, i can saw the sanitizer stopped at

```
==30485==T27 TSDDtor

==30485==T27 exited

==30485==T28: stack [0x2b2b6d23e000,0x2b2b6d43cdc0) size 0x1fedc0; local=0x2b2b6d43ccd4

==30485==T28 TSDDtor

==30485==T28 exited

==30485==T29: stack [0x2b2b6d23e000,0x2b2b6d43cdc0) size 0x1fedc0; local=0x2b2b6d43ccd4

==30485==T29 TSDDtor

==30485==T29 exited

==30485==T30: stack [0x2b2b6d23e000,0x2b2b6d43cdc0) size 0x1fedc0; local=0x2b2b6d43ccd4

==30485==T30 TSDDtor

==30485==T30 exited
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should probably use the GCC version of the address sanitizer. MATLAB on Linux is built with GCC, and it doesn’t officially support other compilers for MEX-files. I think maybe the Clang asan library might interfere with the GCC runtime.

Comment: We used clang to compile mex and c++ codes. Can not switch to gcc due to the portability issue.